# Histogram with variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have done a value count of some data and want to plot a histogram with Yes and No included data. I want age on x axis and frequency on y axis and one colour bar for 'Yes' and another colour for 'No' How do I do this? I am using matplotlib

```
Resigned  Age
No        18      4
          19      3
          20      5
          21      7
          22     11
                 ..
Yes       52      3
          53      2
          55      3
          56      3
          58      5
Length: 82, dtype: int64
```

```
agereg_counts.plot(kind='hist', bins=30) # ratio data

plt.title('Fig. 1 Revolution Consulting - Age Info')

plt.xlabel('Age')
```

and get a weird histogram

PS: This is the complete contents of `agereg_counts`:

```
"{('No', 18): 4, ('No', 19): 3, ('No', 20): 5, ('No', 21): 7, ('No', 22): 11, ('No', 23): 10, ('No', 24): 19, ('No', 25): 20, ('No', 26): 27, ('No', 27): 45, ('No', 28): 34, ('No', 29): 50, ('No', 30): 51, ('No', 31): 51, ('No', 32): 50, ('No', 33): 46, ('No', 34): 68, ('No', 35): 68, ('No', 36): 63, ('No', 37): 44, ('No', 38): 56, ('No', 39): 36, ('No', 40): 52, ('No', 41): 34, ('No', 42): 44, ('No', 43): 30, ('No', 44): 27, ('No', 45): 39, ('No', 46): 29, ('No', 47): 21, ('No', 48): 17, ('No', 49): 22, ('No', 50): 25, ('No', 51): 17, ('No', 52): 15, ('No', 53): 17, ('No', 54): 18, ('No', 55): 19, ('No', 56): 11, ('No', 57): 4, ('No', 58): 9, ('No', 59): 10, ('No', 60): 5, ('Yes', 18): 4, ('Yes', 19): 6, ('Yes', 20): 6, ('Yes', 21): 6, ('Yes', 22): 5, ('Yes', 23): 4, ('Yes', 24): 7, ('Yes', 25): 6, ('Yes', 26): 12, ('Yes', 27): 3, ('Yes', 28): 14, ('Yes', 29): 18, ('Yes', 30): 9, ('Yes', 31): 18, ('Yes', 32): 11, ('Yes', 33): 12, ('Yes', 34): 9, ('Yes', 35): 10, ('Yes', 36): 6, ('Yes', 37): 6, ('Yes', 38): 2, ('Yes', 39): 6, ('Yes', 40): 5, ('Yes', 41): 6, ('Yes', 42): 2, ('Yes', 43): 2, ('Yes', 44): 6, ('Yes', 45): 2, ('Yes', 46): 4, ('Yes', 47): 3, ('Yes', 48): 2, ('Yes', 49): 2, ('Yes', 50): 5, ('Yes', 51): 2, ('Yes', 52): 3, ('Yes', 53): 2, ('Yes', 55): 3, ('Yes', 56): 3, ('Yes', 58): 5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a histogram of all the counts encountered.

To use your `agereg_counts` dataframe, you can convert the `Resigned` index to a normal column (using `.unstack(level=0)`), and then create a bar plot from the counts.

Here is some code, starting from generated test data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20230209)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.randint(18, 60, 500),
                   'Resigned': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], 500)})
agereg_counts = df[['Resigned', 'Age']].value_counts()

agereg_counts.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='bar', rot=0, figsize=(15, 5))

plt.title('Fig. 1 Revolution Consulting - Age Info')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot from counts]

To create a real histogram from your data, it's recommended to use seaborn instead of pandas plotting. Seaborn builds on matplotlib and pandas and provides a lot of functions to ease creating statistical plots.

Note that in your code you put `bins=30`.  This will divide your range from `18` to `58` into 30 equally-sized bins. The bin boundaries would be at `[18.0, 19.33, 20.67, 22.0, 23.33, 24.67, ..., 56.67, 58.0]`. So, the first bin would include 18 and 19, the second bin only 20, the third only 21, the fourth 22 and 23, etc. It would be recommended to explicitly set the bins to give them an equal number of ages.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20230209)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.randint(18, 60, 500),
                   'Resigned': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], 500)})
sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='Age', hue='Resigned', multiple='dodge', bins=np.arange(18.0, 65, 5), shrink=0.8)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot example]

PS: To start directly from your `agereg_count`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

agereg_count_dict = {('No', 18): 4, ('No', 19): 3, ('No', 20): 5, ('No', 21): 7, ('No', 22): 11, ('No', 23): 10, ('No', 24): 19, ('No', 25): 20, ('No', 26): 27, ('No', 27): 45, ('No', 28): 34, ('No', 29): 50, ('No', 30): 51, ('No', 31): 51, ('No', 32): 50, ('No', 33): 46, ('No', 34): 68, ('No', 35): 68, ('No', 36): 63, ('No', 37): 44, ('No', 38): 56, ('No', 39): 36, ('No', 40): 52, ('No', 41): 34, ('No', 42): 44, ('No', 43): 30, ('No', 44): 27, ('No', 45): 39, ('No', 46): 29, ('No', 47): 21, ('No', 48): 17, ('No', 49): 22, ('No', 50): 25, ('No', 51): 17, ('No', 52): 15, ('No', 53): 17, ('No', 54): 18, ('No', 55): 19, ('No', 56): 11, ('No', 57): 4, ('No', 58): 9, ('No', 59): 10, ('No', 60): 5, ('Yes', 18): 4, ('Yes', 19): 6, ('Yes', 20): 6, ('Yes', 21): 6, ('Yes', 22): 5, ('Yes', 23): 4, ('Yes', 24): 7, ('Yes', 25): 6, ('Yes', 26): 12, ('Yes', 27): 3, ('Yes', 28): 14, ('Yes', 29): 18, ('Yes', 30): 9, ('Yes', 31): 18, ('Yes', 32): 11, ('Yes', 33): 12, ('Yes', 34): 9, ('Yes', 35): 10, ('Yes', 36): 6, ('Yes', 37): 6, ('Yes', 38): 2, ('Yes', 39): 6, ('Yes', 40): 5, ('Yes', 41): 6, ('Yes', 42): 2, ('Yes', 43): 2, ('Yes', 44): 6, ('Yes', 45): 2, ('Yes', 46): 4, ('Yes', 47): 3, ('Yes', 48): 2, ('Yes', 49): 2, ('Yes', 50): 5, ('Yes', 51): 2, ('Yes', 52): 3, ('Yes', 53): 2, ('Yes', 55): 3, ('Yes', 56): 3, ('Yes', 58): 5}
agereg_count = pd.Series(agereg_count_dict)

agereg_count.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='bar', rot=0, figsize=(15, 5))
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.title('Fig. 1 Revolution Consulting - Age Info')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot from given data]

Comment: Thank you. Just looking at the graph the count does not seem to be correct. If you look at the raw data for example, in resigned yes age 56 the count is 3 yet in the bar chart it is 11.

Comment: Well, the bar chart isn't from your data, but from simulated test data, where `yes age 56` is in 11 rows.  You only provided very limited data.

Comment: Is there a way to send you the full data set as I still can't get it to work correctly at my end. Thanks

Comment: Supposing your dataframe is called `df`, using `str(df.to_dict('list'))`, you could copy-paste your data into your original post.  Or `str(agereg_counts.to_dict())` if you want to include only `agerege_counts`. (Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75392493/edit) to edit your post.)

Comment: Similar data. that is complete

Resigned OverTime 
No           No  944
                  Yes         289
Yes           No  110
            Yes 127

Comment: I added the agereg_count data